# How do you create an oval with border-radius in CSS?

Tags: css

I need an oval instead of a rectangle with rounded edges.

Here's the code I'm using.

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  border-radius: 25px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5)
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  top: calc(50% - 25px);
  right: calc(50% - 50px);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use `border-radius: 50%` instead :)

```css
div {
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Set `border-radius` as a percentage.

```
div {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [link](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) 
which will explain all the different shapes you need.

Following is an example on how you can achieve it.

```
   #round {
      position: relative;
      width: 100px;
      height: 100px;
      margin: 20px 0;
      background: orange;
      border-radius: 48% / 25%;
      color: white;
    }
    #round:before {
      content: '';
      position: absolute;
      top: 10%;
      bottom: 11%;
      right: -5%;
      left: -5%;
      background: inherit;
      border-radius: 21% / 68%;
    }


    <div id="round"></div>
```